# How to use twitter bootstrap and zf2 action?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I have a  view with some table data from database and i need to add button with poup dialog to edit it within a form, the button:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="<?php
  echo $this->url('admin', array(
      'action' => 'manage',
      'controller' => 'settings-api',
      'id' => $formdata['id'])); ?>"
  data-target="#edit_modal">Edit</a>
```

the popup container:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="edit_modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Edit form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

in controller action i have something like this:

```
if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
    $view->setTerminal(true); 

$id = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
$form->setData($data[$id]);
return $view->setVariables(array('form' => $form));
```

and when im clicking to the button i have a popup and firebug shows me that i have a GET to action with id i need, but if i close popup without postig a data and click again to another button with another id i have no request to the action no more, i have just popup with old data
Someone can tell me what im doing wrong??

Comment: Sounds to me very much like a jQuery error, so it might be best to post your modal function stuff, too, as the PHP Side is pretty much stable.

Comment: i have no jquery stuff, only the html+php that i posted

Comment: As this is only parts of your view, i can only guess. One thing for sure though the PHP Part is ok.

Comment: i told you i have no additional jquery code for this

Comment: But you told us you have multiple buttons and i see only code for one button and the error clearly is not on the ZF2 part, that's why my assumption is that the error is somewhere within your views where u create all those button/tables/whatever :)

Comment: [link](http://pastie.org/5122598) here it is, foreach just building the table and buttons, the problem is i having a resquest only once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18655/discussion-between---and-sam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used jquery from remote server and when i downladed it and connect it  local from my server, its working, but why its dosent working with the romote?
And its still dosent working if im tring to set

```
$form->setData($apiClient[$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id')]);
return $view->setVariables(array('form' => $form));
```

Just working with `var_dump($form);`

Comment: It at least should be `$form->setData(array('id' => $apiClient[...]));`

Comment: [the page](http://2xcash.ru/admin/settings-api/), maybe some one can look and tell what is wrong?

Comment: I have no clue where the JS is defined that handles the popup, but one thing that's bad is after first popup, theres a JS error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'` Fix that first and see how it goes from that point.

Comment: just forget to connect jquery UI, but it dosent work, it works only if i connecting the scripts in my view that render a form for popup, but its not the right way i think